# How to play .ts video file on wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming, playback

**I have a problem and can't solved it. Please anyone help me who know good way for play .ts file on wordpress site**

My teacher give the task yesterday that, Play the video file those save on server bur I confused when I see the extension of file is *.ts . Now I have the just one url `"http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/song/"` like this. Kindly guide me how I play on wordpress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No browser can play a ts (FYI ts = transport stream). ts is the basis for HLS but you will need a manifest (m3u8). And even then only safari can play it. Your solution would be to convert the file to mp4, and use a html video tag

Comment: How I convert files that present on sever I have just access these file no much more.. @szatmary ?

Comment: Download and convert. Then host the file from the same place as your wordpesss site.